# Coding If -then do from SAS to SQL using CASE WHEN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sas

I have a code in SAS that I wish to write in SQL. It uses if-then do.

```
if x>0 and y>0 and z<0 then do
a=x
b=y+x
c=0

else if x<0 and y<0 and z>0 then do
a=0
b=-y
c=z
```

I wish to know if I can use CASE WHEN statement to recreate this type of code in SQL. a,b,c are new columns(variables) that are created. x,y,z are present in my table.
Any help with this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In a stored procedure?

Comment: So you are creating three target variables, so you need three separated CASE clauses, one in each of the expressions that is used to create those variables.

Comment: You still haven't exhausted all the possibilities, how do you want the branching to end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it once for each variable you want to create instead, rather than looking at it by conditions something along the lines of the following:

```
case when X>0 & y>0 & z<0 then X
else when x<0 & y<0 & z>0 then 0
end as a,
case when X>0 & y>0 & z<0 then X+Y
else when x<0 & y<0 & z>0 then -Y
end as b,
case when X>0 & y>0 & z<0 then 0
else when x<0 & y<0 & z>0 then Z
end as c,
```